# JSF2 and custom components - how to call action from Javascript code?

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have adapted a Pie chart JS object to use with JSF; in order to do so, I've created a custom component that outputs the appropriate markup and JS calls on the page, rendering the graph correctly. For reference's sake, [this is the link](http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/) for the tutorial I've followed for the JS part.

The next step is listening to clicks on the slices, and calling an action from a backing bean. The JS object for the chart already contains a placeholder function that listens to such clicks, so I believe the JS part of it is good. However, the JSF side bugs me still; I've read the Java EE tutorial, Jim Driscoll's blog posts, and all over the internet, and still can't get my head around it.

So, could anyone be so kind as to give a little example, of how I could bind a JS function call to an event listener in JSF, so that my backing bean would be nicely informed of which slice index had been clicked by the user?

It would be something close to:

```
function myChartObject() {

    function onSliceClick() {
        // This will somehow trigger JSF ajax event listener with slice data
    }
}

class MyCustomChart extends UIComponentBase implements ClientBehaviorHolder {
    // Is the decode() method the place to bind JS calls to JSF actions?
}
```

The closest I've found to my problem is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851795/call-from-javascript-to-server-side-code-in-jsf). However, I'd like to have this support in my own component, using the standard JSF API. Something perhaps close to [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/10/09/jsf-2-custom-java-components-and-ajax-behaviors)?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSF Javascript API to do AJAX calls is itself standardized (resource library "javax.faces", resource name "jsf.js") but adding full AJAX support in your own Java based custom component is a little elaborate.

The quickest way I can think of is following the blog by Jim Driscoll that you cited, and re-use the existing AJAX machinery offered by the `<f:ajax>` tag by wrapping your own Java based custom component in a composite component.

In Jim's example, I guess the following code from line 22 in his example is what you should render inside your `onSliceClick` function:

```
String click = behaviors.get("click").get(0).getScript(behaviorContext);
```

It would then look a little like this:

```
<ui:component
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:cu="http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/demo/custom-taglib" 
>
    <cc:interface shortDescription="Some Description">
        <cc:attribute name="render" required="false" />     
        <cc:attribute name="clickAction" method-signature="java.lang.Object action" required="true" shortDescription="The click action method" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <cu:custom id="customId">
            <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.render}" listener="#{cc.attrs.clickAction}"/>
        </cu:custom>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Note that I haven't tested this, but it's the general idea. Of course it's also possible to do all of it directly in Java code but that surely takes some more work.

Comment: I guess there's no way around it, but to try to simplify the component itself a little bit. If you look at the JS chart, the call to the slice click is tied to the canvas component - the author uses geometry to identify if the click has been over a slice, and then calls the JS function that triggers events. Binding anything to this  JS behavior in a Java custom component is going to be difficult..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the ability to encode ajax style behaviors in your java compiled code, while integrating this with a J2ee stack.

**The framework that comes to mind is JBOSS's Seam**

1. Seam integrates directly with JSF by design, (GWT is more of a lightweight, standalone, statefull web-application framework - it doesn't have a lot of embedded features for direct integration with JMS and other modern J2ee features)...
2. Seam directly supports GWT-style ajax enabled components.

There is a good tutorial here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-seam3/

Comment: I do know Seam, but it's not an option for this project. And again, the question is more related to JSF custom component development, which should be framework agnostic in the first place. But thanks for your time :)